# EF Core 2.2 - can't add new record with link to already existing another one

Tags: entity-framework-core

My POCO classes:

```
[Table]
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<CategoryProduct> CategoryProducts { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryProduct
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}


[Table]
public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<CategoryProduct> CategoryProducts { get; set; }
}
```

Here's a function for inserting new records:

```
async Task CreateProduct(Product dto)
        {
                await ctx.Products.AddAsync(dto);
                await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
```

In dto I pass the following JSON:

```
{
        "name": "Gr&#228;ff Stettin",
        "categoryProducts": [{
                "categoryId": 1,
                "productId": 1,
                "category": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Drinks"
                }
            }, {
                "categoryId": 2,
                "productId": 1,
                "category": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Alcohol"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

As a result, at SaveChangesAsync() I get an exception with message regarding attempt to insert already existing Category. Tracing shows the following query:

```
INSERT INTO "Category" ("Id", "Name") VALUES (@p0, @p1);
```

How should I change my CreateProduct() method to avoid attempts to add categories with already existing categoryId?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [AutoMapper](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html) and ignore category =

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<categoryProductsDto,categoryProducts>())
.ForMember(u => u.Category, options => options.Ignore());
```

and use mapper =

```
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

categoryProducts entity = mapper.Map<categoryProducts>(input);
 await _categoryProductsRepository.InsertAndGetIdAsync(entity);
```